# How to combine/merge two audio .wav files into one file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, wav

How could I merge or combine two audio.wav loaded from url into a new .wav and play it in the web browser and download it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The HTML and JS code:**

*NOTE: To avoid cross-origin load wavs from your local or server or allow it in your .htaccess*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta content="text/html;" http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8">
    <head>
    
    <script>
    
     window.onload = function() {
    

        //Original Wav
        //https://www.wavsource.com/snds_2020-10-01_3728627494378403/video_games/pacman/pacman_intro.wav
        var audioFileUrl1 = 'pacman_intro.wav';  //Atention to cross-origin** !!!
        var audioFileUrl2 = 'pacman_intro.wav'; //I love PacMan intro :P
        
        loadWav(audioFileUrl1, audioFileUrl2); //Load wavs from url

        function loadWav(url1,url2){
            
            var arrBytesWav1, arrBytesWav2;
            
            fetch(url1)
            .then(function(response) { return response.blob(); })
            .then(function(blob) {
                
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
                reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
                    arrBytesWav1 = reader.result;
                });
                    
                return fetch(url2); //Return the second url as a Promise.
            })
            //Second load 
            .then(function(response) { return response.blob(); })
            .then(function(blob) {
                
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
                reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
                    arrBytesWav2 = reader.result;
                    combineWavsBuffers( arrBytesWav1, arrBytesWav2 ); //Combine original wav buffer and play
                });

            })          
            .catch( function(error) {
                alert('Error wav loading: ' + error.message);
            });

        }
        
        
        //Combine two audio .wav buffers and assign to audio control and play it.
        function combineWavsBuffers(buffer1, buffer2) {
                
                //Combine array bytes of original wavs buffers
                var tmp = new Uint8Array(buffer1.byteLength + buffer2.byteLength);
                tmp.set( new Uint8Array(buffer1), 0 );
                tmp.set( new Uint8Array(buffer2), buffer1.byteLength );
    
                //Get buffer1 audio data to create the new combined wav
                var audioData = getAudioData.WavHeader.readHeader(new DataView(buffer1));
                console.log('Audio Data: ', audioData); 
    
    
                //Send combined buffer and send audio data to create the audio data of combined 
                var arrBytesFinal = getWavBytes( tmp, {
                  isFloat: false,       // floating point or 16-bit integer
                  numChannels: audioData.channels,
                  sampleRate: audioData.sampleRate,
                })              
                    
                //Create a Blob as Base64 Raw data with audio/wav type
                var myBlob = new Blob( [arrBytesFinal] , { type : 'audio/wav; codecs=MS_PCM' });
                var combineBase64Wav;
                var readerBlob = new FileReader();
                readerBlob.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
                    combineBase64Wav = readerBlob.result.toString();
                    //Assign to audiocontrol to play the new combined wav.
                    var audioControl = document.getElementById('audio');
                    audioControl.src = combineBase64Wav;
                    audioControl.play();              
                });
                readerBlob.readAsDataURL(myBlob);
    
                console.log( "Buffer1 Size: "  + buffer1.byteLength );
                console.log( "Buffer2 Size: "  + buffer1.byteLength );
                console.log( "Combined Size: " + arrBytesFinal.byteLength );
                
                return combineBase64Wav;
    
        }
        
            
        
        //Other functions //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         
        // Returns Uint8Array of WAV bytes
        function getWavBytes(buffer, options) {
          const type = options.isFloat ? Float32Array : Uint16Array
          const numFrames = buffer.byteLength / type.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
        
          const headerBytes = getWavHeader(Object.assign({}, options, { numFrames }))
          const wavBytes = new Uint8Array(headerBytes.length + buffer.byteLength);
        
          // prepend header, then add pcmBytes
          wavBytes.set(headerBytes, 0)
          wavBytes.set(new Uint8Array(buffer), headerBytes.length)
        
          return wavBytes
        }
        
        // adapted from https://gist.github.com/also/900023
        // returns Uint8Array of WAV header bytes
        function getWavHeader(options) {
          const numFrames =      options.numFrames
          const numChannels =    options.numChannels || 2
          const sampleRate =     options.sampleRate || 44100
          const bytesPerSample = options.isFloat? 4 : 2
          const format =         options.isFloat? 3 : 1
        
          const blockAlign = numChannels * bytesPerSample
          const byteRate = sampleRate * blockAlign
          const dataSize = numFrames * blockAlign
        
          const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44)
          const dv = new DataView(buffer)
        
          let p = 0
        
          function writeString(s) {
            for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
              dv.setUint8(p + i, s.charCodeAt(i))
            }
            p += s.length
          }
        
          function writeUint32(d) {
            dv.setUint32(p, d, true)
            p += 4
          }
        
          function writeUint16(d) {
            dv.setUint16(p, d, true)
            p += 2
          }
        
          writeString('RIFF')              // ChunkID
          writeUint32(dataSize + 36)       // ChunkSize
          writeString('WAVE')              // Format
          writeString('fmt ')              // Subchunk1ID
          writeUint32(16)                  // Subchunk1Size
          writeUint16(format)              // AudioFormat
          writeUint16(numChannels)         // NumChannels
          writeUint32(sampleRate)          // SampleRate
          writeUint32(byteRate)            // ByteRate
          writeUint16(blockAlign)          // BlockAlign
          writeUint16(bytesPerSample * 8)  // BitsPerSample
          writeString('data')              // Subchunk2ID
          writeUint32(dataSize)            // Subchunk2Size
        
          return new Uint8Array(buffer)
        }


        function getAudioData(){
    
        
            function WavHeader() {
                this.dataOffset = 0;
                this.dataLen = 0;
                this.channels = 0;
                this.sampleRate = 0;
            }
            
            function fourccToInt(fourcc) {
                return fourcc.charCodeAt(0) << 24 | fourcc.charCodeAt(1) << 16 | fourcc.charCodeAt(2) << 8 | fourcc.charCodeAt(3);
            }
            
            WavHeader.RIFF = fourccToInt("RIFF");
            WavHeader.WAVE = fourccToInt("WAVE");
            WavHeader.fmt_ = fourccToInt("fmt ");
            WavHeader.data = fourccToInt("data");
            
            WavHeader.readHeader = function (dataView) {
                var w = new WavHeader();
            
                var header = dataView.getUint32(0, false);
                if (WavHeader.RIFF != header) {
                    return;
                }
                var fileLen = dataView.getUint32(4, true);
                if (WavHeader.WAVE != dataView.getUint32(8, false)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (WavHeader.fmt_ != dataView.getUint32(12, false)) {
                    return;
                }
                var fmtLen = dataView.getUint32(16, true);
                var pos = 16 + 4;
                switch (fmtLen) {
                    case 16:
                    case 18:
                        w.channels = dataView.getUint16(pos + 2, true);
                        w.sampleRate = dataView.getUint32(pos + 4, true);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw 'extended fmt chunk not implemented';
                }
                pos += fmtLen;
                var data = WavHeader.data;
                var len = 0;
                while (data != header) {
                    header = dataView.getUint32(pos, false);
                    len = dataView.getUint32(pos + 4, true);
                    if (data == header) {
                        break;
                    }
                    pos += (len + 8);
                }
                w.dataLen = len;
                w.dataOffset = pos + 8;
                return w;
            };
        
            getAudioData.WavHeader = WavHeader;
        
        }
        
        getAudioData();

        
        
    };//Window onLoad
    
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    
    <!--The audio control HTML element -->
    <audio id="audio" src="" controls></audio>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Such a great solution! I found out that this is the best solution ever, I recommend it.

Thanks!

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks , alot i was searching for solution like this since 2019....

Comment: @JTCon Do you know anyway to do this for png files? I have 2 canvases which I turn into blobs and then png download. Both can download seperatley but I need to put them in the same file, one above the other. Thanks