# how to concatenate multiple .webm audio files into one file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, blob, webm

I am fetching audio chunks, with .webm extension, from S3 bucket and want to concatenate all audio chunks into a single audio file which I can download.

I have already tried [concatenateBlob.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/ConcatenateBlobs) but couldn't achieve what I want, it did combine all audio files and works fine when I play it in the browser but when I download the audio file and play the audio, only the first audio chunk is played even though size of the concatenated file is correct.

I believe it has to do something with the header of final blob as explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68070127/how-can-i-merge-multiple-wav-audio-blobs-into-one)
but it talks about modifying headers of only wav files which is diff from webm files. Kindly help me sort this out

P.S. I want to do  this concatenation in the browser, not on the backend

Comment: Are those audio chunks each discrete WebM files, or chunks of a single WebM file?

Comment: chunks of single audio recording

Comment: It sounds like your .webm segments all have init segments. You need to remove the init segments from the 2nd segment onwards before concatenating, however at this time I'm not sure how you do that.

Answer (score -2):

You can pass the individual segments of the single file to Media Source Extensions for playback, and simultaneously capture and record an `<audio>` element with `HTMLMediaElement.captureStream()` and `MediaRecorder()`.

Comment: can you provide any code reference

Comment: I did this around 10 different ways here  https://github.com/guest271314/MediaFragmentRecorder